# Meteor SSR "Error: Can't render undefined"

Tags: node.js, api, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to get server-side rendering using IronRouter and Meteor-SSR in a basic Meteor app. When I load `/home` in the browser I get the following error:

```
Error: Can't render undefined
    at checkRenderContent (packages/blaze.js:702:11)
    at contentAsView (packages/blaze.js:724:3)
    at Blaze.toHTML (packages/blaze.js:851:40)
    at Object.SSR.render (packages/meteorhacks_ssr.js:208:10)
    at [object Object].Router.route.where (main.js:9:20)
    at boundNext (packages/iron_middleware-stack.js:408:31)
    at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor.js:1176:24)
    at packages/meteor.js:1189:14
    at [object Object].urlencodedParser (/Users/roger/.meteor/packages/iron_router/.1.1.1.1q7cd8x++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules1/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:84:40)
    at packages/iron_router.js:886:36
```

Here's the code for the app:

```
// main.js

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Router.route('/home', function() {
    let html = SSR.render('home');
    this.response.end(html);
  }, {where: 'server'});
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Router.route('/home', function() {
    this.render("home")
  });
}
```

Here's `main.html`:

```
<head>
  <title>SSR Test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>

<template name="home">
  Home
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your `home` template is not defined on server. To use `SSR` package, you need to compile the template in your server with `SSR.compileTemplate` first, only then you could render it with `SSR.render`. This is a simple example for you:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  const template = 'Hello {{username}}, <br> Now time is: {{time}}';
  SSR.compileTemplate('hello', template);

  Router.route('/home', function() {
    const html = SSR.render('hello', {
      username: 'foo',
      time: new Date(),
    });

    this.response.end(html);
  }, {where: 'server'});
}
```

There is also a better to compile template from static file on server which could be found [here](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr#better-way-to-load-templates)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to easily load the templates already defined in main.html? The documentation for meteor-ssr says "Previously, this package loads all the client side templates when your app starts. But now meteor don't allow us to do that. So that behaviour has been removed.". Is there some way to implement this behavior?